# Identifying saturated liquid and using property table

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation, liquid-state

I just know how to use thermodynamics property table in some textbooks. However, in practice, for example in industries, how can people usually use the property table?

Moreover, how can we identify that water is already in saturated region in industrial application? Is there a way to measure it?

Thank you

Comment: Relative humidity sensors are pretty cheap.